# Embed Ads in C++ Win32 API GUI Application?

Tags: c++, winapi, ads

I've created a program using C++ Win32 API and wanted to add some ads to it and hopefully make money off of it. As an Android developer its always been as easy as finding a mobile ad network and implementing within 10 minutes but I don't see anything like that for windows applications written in C++. Another idea I had was implementing HTML ads inside the program, but I don't know exactly how that would work either. Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Microsoft offers a framework to display ads for Windows Store Apps (and Windows Phone) only. See [Get started with Microsoft Advertising and Ads in Apps](http://adsinapps.microsoft.com/en-us).

Comment: What if I were to implement this but not put in on their store? The program I'm making is for Windows XP and up and the windows store is only Windows 8/8.1

Comment: You cannot write Windows Store Apps for Windows prior to version 8. You cannot use the Ad SDK for Desktop Applications, either, which appears to be what you are after.

Comment: Damn. Do you know of any other ways?

Comment: I assume you could host a [WebBrowser Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752040.aspx), and feed it with your ad stream.

Comment: For Google Ads, I remember that Google do not allow using ads inside of a Windows program, because you can easily simulate ads clicking inside of your program. And I think the time that you can make money by developing a Window software is past.